# how to prevent from getting wrong ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, primary-key

database= mysql language=php

I am coding  program to work like this

PC1 =computer1

step

1.PC1 insert data ,new ID from Auto-increment.

2.PC1 select  last ID

everything work fine but..

The problem when your code is used by many computers at the same mili-sec. 
For example

1. PC1insert data,Auto-increment new ID

2.PC2 insert data ,Auto-increment new ID

3.PC1 select last ID <-------Wrong

4PC2 select last ID

How to config database or modify php code to prevent this , thankyou.

Comment: can you post your code on how you fetch the last id?

Comment: I didn't finish the code yet, I just think it may cause the problem when I code it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) (or the equivalent call for the API you are using) to get the ID of the last inserted row.

I imagine that now you are doing this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourtable
```

This won't work unless you use transactions. But using the function `mysql_insert_id` is the better way.

---

In the documenation there is also a caution and some notes that you should read:

> **Caution**: mysql_insert_id() will convert the return type of the native MySQL C API function mysql_insert_id() to a type of long (named int in PHP). If your AUTO_INCREMENT column has a column type of BIGINT (64 bits) the conversion may result in an incorrect value. Instead, use the internal MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() in an SQL query.
>
> **Note**: Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value.
>
> **Note**: The value of the MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() always contains the most recently generated AUTO_INCREMENT value, and is not reset between queries.

Comment: or PDO::lastInsertID() / mysqli_insert_id depending on the connection of choice. But indeed this value is session-safe.

Comment: Careful though: According to the docs, `mysql_insert_id()` should be called immediately after the insert query, while mySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` can be called later as long as it's the same connection.

Comment: I've added the warnings from the documentation to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

in mysql if you call

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

you will get the last auto generated id fro the current connection, not for the whole server. So if another record is created in another connection it wont effect the result returned by LAST_INSERT_ID().

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will return the correct last-inserted ID right after any `INSERT` statement per client (computer) connection, so you won't have to worry about that; the server won't mix them up. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html):

> Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.

As long as you call `mysql_insert_id()` in your PHP code to retrieve the insert ID, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

mySQL has the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) function for that.

The PHP equivalent (if you use the classical mysql functions) is [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) with the exception that this function should be called **immediately** after the INSERT query because it acts on the last query made.

These functions work on a per-*connection* basis, it will not be influenced by records inserted by other clients.